# A question on the Gamma function for real argument

Tags: real-analysis, gamma-function

The Gamma Function for real argument being defined by $$\Gamma(x)=\int_0^{\infty} t^{x-1} e^{-t}dt$$
Prove the equality $$\Gamma(\frac 23)\Gamma(\frac 76)=\Gamma(\frac 53)\Gamma(\frac 16)$$ Remarking that $\frac 23+\frac 76=\frac {11}{6}=\frac53+\frac 16$ it appears the following question:
is it true that $$\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)=\Gamma(c)\Gamma(d)\space\text{when}\space a+b=c+d?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true.

The basic idea is that
$\Gamma(x+1)
=x\Gamma(x)
$.

Therefore,
$\Gamma(\frac53)
=\frac23 \Gamma(\frac23)
$
and
$\Gamma(\frac76)
=\frac16 \Gamma(\frac16)
$
so that

$\begin{array}\\
\Gamma(\frac 23)\Gamma(\frac 76)-\Gamma(\frac 53)\Gamma(\frac 16)
&=\Gamma(\frac 23)\frac16 \Gamma(\frac16)-\frac23 \Gamma(\frac23)\Gamma(\frac 16)\\
&=(\frac16-\frac23)\Gamma(\frac 23) \Gamma(\frac16)\\
&=-\frac12\Gamma(\frac 23) \Gamma(\frac16)\\
&\approx -3.768724\\
&\ne 0
\end{array}
$

Comment: I am really sorry: I had in hand the (true) equality $\frac {\Gamma(2/3)}{\Gamma (1/6)}=\frac{\Gamma (5/3)}{4\Gamma(7/6)}$ and I inconsiderate, by unforgivable distraction, the number $4$ to built the question.

Comment: even if it had not been the number 4, I was expecting for a negative answer because of  "indirect reasoning": if that were true, it would be a well-known property of the gamma function. Thank you.